# JSF outputText and PrimeExtensions inputNumber

Tags: jsf, primefaces, primefaces-extensions

I'm using the component pe:inputNumber for my BigDecimal values, all works fine, but I coundn't find (yet) a solution to just display the data exactly as the pe:inputNumber displays without using the inputNumber component with the readonly...

I mean, I just need a simple h:outputText with the exact pe:inputNumber formated value... Is this possible?

Thanks.

Comment: I already tried this and didn't worked, that was the reason I am using primefaces extension instead the simple f:convertNumber pattern thing.

Comment: It must work. So you did something wrong. But the root cause is not visible in the information provided so far. Edit the question to include a MCVE, complete with a detailed description of expected input and output.

Comment: it was indeed duplicated, the related topic solved my problem in parts, with some little further modifications, it worked. Thanks